# How to use different contacts on different iPhones with the same Apple ID

Tags: iphone, contacts, apple-id

My daughter and I use two iPhones, both connected to the same Apple ID. At the moment I see my daughter's contacts merged to my contact list, but we'd like to use our contact lists separately from each other.

I met the similar issue when I set up FaceTime, however that issue was resolved by using different emails in FaceTime settings. It looks like I can't solve the issue with contacts the same way.

Does anybody know how to use different contacts on different iPhones with the same Apple ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can see for sharing an Apple ID is to share purchases.  Otherwise as you have found out, you are sharing contacts, calendars, emails and maybe even video calls and imessages etc.

Luckily, whilst all the above are iCloud functions, they are not mapped to your App Store account, and you can sign into separate accounts for each of these functions on your device.

So, on the assumption that the above is your scenario, then just sign into the App Store with the existing Apple ID which then is only responsible for purchases and download authentication etc., and then one of you can sign up for a separate free iCloud account to handle all the other functions.